# Trouble understanding the $ε$-$N$ proof for limit of sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm currently stuck on a math problem proposed by my teacher.

> For $\varepsilon=0,001$, find $N=N_0$ such that $|a_n-L|\lt \varepsilon$ if $n\geqslant N$
>
> $$a_n = \frac{(n+1)}{3n-1}\, {\rm and} \, L=1/3$$

According to him, the answer could be any $N_0$ greater than $\left[\frac{2}{3\varepsilon}\right]+1$. I have an idea of how the proof works, but I can't figure out how he came up with that specific value for N$_0$. And why the final value has a $+1$.

Comment: In general, the purpose of a formula for $N_0$ is so that when you use that formula in the proof, the proof will work. The formula your teacher used gives a much larger than minimal value of $N_0,$ which is fine (you can never go wrong by setting $N_0$ larger than needed), but to know the reason for choosing that _particular_ formula it might help to see the specific steps of the proof.

Comment: Note that the standard in the English speaking world is to use the period to denote decimals ($\epsilon =.001$).

Comment: @Acccumulation Note that the standard is not to skip the leading zero as well, $\epsilon = 0.001$.

Answer (score 6):

We have that

$$\left|\frac{n+1}{3n-1}-\frac13\right|<\epsilon \iff \frac{4}{3(3n-1)}<\epsilon. $$

Now

$$\frac{4}{3(3n-1)}<\epsilon\iff 9n-3>\frac{4}{\epsilon}\iff 9n>\frac{4}{\epsilon}+3.$$ So we need

$$n>\frac{4}{9\epsilon}+\frac13.$$ So it is enough to have

$$n>\left[\frac{4}{9\epsilon}\right]+\left[\frac13\right]=\left[\frac{4}{9\epsilon}\right]+1.$$

Comment: Almost identical answers! You were quicker though. =)

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$ a_n - L = \frac{n+1}{3n-1}- \frac{1}{3} = \frac{3(n+1)-(3n-1)}{3(3n-1)} = \frac{4}{3(3n-1)}. $$
So we want
$$ \frac{4}{3(3n-1)} < \epsilon \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad 3n-1 > \frac{4}{3\epsilon} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad n > \frac{4}{9\epsilon}+\frac{1}{3}, $$
so we can take
$$ n_0 = \left[ \frac{4}{9\epsilon}\right] + 1. $$
We have $+1$ here to be on the safe side, since we want the previous inequality to be *strict*.

In particular, if $\epsilon = 0.001 =  10^{-3}$ this becomes
$$ n_0 = \left[ \frac{4000}{9}\right]+1 = \left[ \frac{4000}{9}\right]+1 = 445. $$